# Do they notice me if I use /d/ instead of 'th' sound?

Tags: pronunciation, th

I can’t hear the difference between /d/ and **th** very well, though I know how to pronounce them. And it’s always hard for my tongue to use **th**, especially in the word “the”. Naturally I switch to /d/ sound. Is it a big deal? Or how could I improve my **th** sound?

Comment: Question: if you can't hear de difference, how do you know how to pronounce dem?

Comment: Yes, we can hear the difference between *"/th/e"* and *"/d/e"*.  It's little sounds like that which distinguish the different accents of various native and non-native English speakers.  For example, just yesterday I was watching a TV show with Jamaican characters who pronounced *"thing"* like *"ting"*, and which I couldn't help but try (poorly) to imitate.

Comment: @Andrew for me, it’s hard to hear the difference between unvoiced /th/ and /s/. So sometimes I say some/s/ing instead of /th/ because it’s hard to switch from /s/ to /th/. Is it quite noticeable?

Comment: The tongue is closer in position to make the TH sound in something, than it is to make a S sound in its place. Say "some" and as you finish the me breathe out to make the TH sound.

Comment: @user67265  Yes, very much so.  Substituting "s" for "th" is not uncommon, and is in fact one of the key parts of imitating a stereotypical "French" accent in English.

Comment: These differences are noticeable because they are [phonological](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phonology) differences that make a [semantic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/semantic) difference.  We notice the difference because **those** and **doze**, and **thing** and **sing** don't just sound different, they mean something different too.

Comment: @Lambie I learned how to pronounce it. And I can hear the difference if you say them side by side. But it’s hard to tell in speech.

Comment: @stangdon Yeah, but I disagree that's the reason why you notice them. In fact, I think you don't notice them at all in fast speech (hence the approximations such as /d/ instead of /ð/) which is due to the context. You can't possibly mishear *those* as *doze*. If the speaker isn't as proficient, however, you might struggle to figure out what they're trying to say **because** you're plucking the words (such as *thing* that sounds like *sing*) out of the context.

Comment: @user67265 I don't think it's a big deal to switch to the /d/ sound, but it depends on the situation. However, the only way to do it naturally is to first learn to pronounce words correctly, and then when you encounter difficulties in executing the whole movement (for example, if you've learned to pronounce the /θ/ sound by sticking your tongue out between your teeth, that'll soon become difficult in fast speech), you'll naturally resort to the described approximation which won't register with native speakers of English as unnatural-sounding.

Comment: @userr2684291 do you mean it sounds natural in fast speech?

Comment: @userr2684291 - I think it IS a big deal. It's what differentiates anything close to 'standard' english from the already mentioned Jamaican accent [dis ting], or in the UK, Liverpool [scouse] .. colloquially referred to as "di doo dat dere doh don't di doh" Try saying that without sounding scouse ;) *[trans: they do that there, though, don't they, though]* which is an over-the-top stereotypification.

Comment: @Tetsujin Trust me, it's not. Please read this answer: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/278970/71740. By the way, thanks for the laugh. (:

Comment: @user67265 Of course. Please visit the above link.

Comment: @userr2684291 from your link, I really can't get a d out of the example sentence, unless I'm talking scouse or telling someone which supermarket I've just got back from - 'Asda went' ;) I can easily see the z sound replacing it, 'az zer went' but not the d. [and I just found the scouse quote re-quoted in the comments ;-)) Didn't know it was Stan Boardman.

Comment: @userr2684291- I completely agree that we often understand things correctly because we "just know" what the speaker meant, and a learner will have trouble with that.  I disagree that we don't notice them at all: consider the stereotype of the New York gangster saying "*dese* and *dose*", or the Jamaican saying "a *likkle ting*".  re phonological & semantic differences, it's the difference between using /d/ vs /θ/ and using aspirated vs unaspirated *p*, which is a phonological difference without a semantic difference; there's nowhere that *p* vs *p^h* makes a minimal pair, unlike *d* vs /θ/.

Comment: @stangdon Sorry, it was late when I wrote that. I meant /ð/ vs. /d/ and /θ/ vs. /t/, but I think the point was understood nevertheless. Anyway, please read the linked answer. I'm not talking about slow speech or intentionally stressing certain sounds, but fast and relaxed speech in which native speakers of a language make certain sounds unconsciously. The answer I linked to explains it better than I'd ever be able to.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it’s noticeable. It’s somewhat of an issue because those sounds are very common in English. I feel it is more stylistic than correctness, however here is how I make the /th/ sound.

Try to touch your tongue to the bottoms of all of your upper teeth like the first photo below.

[image]

Keep your tongue flat and using it to touch the bottom of all of your upper teeth (don't put your tongue inside your upper teeth instead put it perpendicular to your teeth just like when you bite your tongue. Next try to lower your bottom jaw a bit like the (second) picture below (exaggerated in photo because you can't keep your tongue touching all of your upper teeth *and* lower your bottom jaw very much). It's just so you can get some air flow though your mouth.

[image]

Try the mouth technique above and breaking up the words like this:

- th-e (pronounced th-uh)
- th-is (pronounced th-iss)
- th-at (pronounced th-at)

In practice:

- First, make your /d/ sound (but with your tongue flat against all of your upper teeth and your lower jaw slightly lowered). It will have more of a /z/ sound than a /d/ sound.
- Next, make your /th/ sound **while exhaling** out through your mouth (with your tongue flat against all of your upper teeth and your lower jaw slightly lowered). The exhale should produce more of a /th/ than a /z/ sound.
- Only release your tongue from touching your teeth after you have made the /th/ sound.
- Say the second part of the word.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, native speakers will absolutely notice if you use /d/ instead of /the/. It's one of the key things that gives away a lot of non-native speakers.